# Estou criando uma trigger para inserir dados em uma tabela log, porém o SQL Server está retornando erro

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, ssms

A tabela de histórico só irá receber estes valores, assim que for atualizado os dados na tabela de anúncio, enviando os dados anteriores da atualização.

Mensagem de erro:

> "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TG_INCLUSAO_HISTORICO, Line 42 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Invalid column name 'TB_ANUNCIO'."

```
    GO
CREATE TRIGGER TG_INCLUSAO_HISTORICO
ON TB_ANUNCIO
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @Id_Anuncio INT,
    @Id_Evento INT,
    @Nome_anuncio VARCHAR(100),
    @Descricao VARCHAR(500),
    @Valor MONEY,
    @Qtd INT,
    @Sn_Img BIT,
    @Nm_Categoria VARCHAR(100),
    @Nm_Situacao VARCHAR(100),
    @Nm_Modelo VARCHAR(100),
    @Nm_Marca VARCHAR(100),
    @Nm_Condicao VARCHAR(100),
    @Nm_Tipo_Anuncio VARCHAR(100)

    SELECT @Id_Anuncio = TBA.ID_ANUNCIO ,@Id_Evento = TBH.ID_EVENTO, @Nome_anuncio = TBA.NM_ANUNCIO, 
    @Descricao = TBA.DS_ANUNCIO, @Valor = TBA.VL_ANUNCIO,
    @Qtd = TBA.QT_ANUNCIADA, @Sn_Img = 1 ,@Nm_Categoria = CAT.NM_CATEGORIA, @Nm_Situacao = TBS.NM_SITUACAO,
    @Nm_Modelo = TBMO.NM_MODELO, @Nm_Categoria = TBMA.NM_MARCA, @Nm_Condicao = TBC.NM_CONDICAO,
    @Nm_Tipo_Anuncio = TBTA.NM_TIPO_ANUNCIO
    FROM TB_ANUNCIO TBA
    INNER JOIN TB_HISTORICO TBH
    ON TBA.ID_ANUNCIO = TBH.ID_ANUNCIO
    INNER JOIN TB_CATEGORIA CAT
    ON TBA.ID_ANUNCIO = CAT.ID_CATEGORIA
    INNER JOIN TB_SITUACAO TBS
    ON TBA.ID_SITUACAO = TBS.ID_SITUACAO
    INNER JOIN TB_MODELO TBMO
    ON TBA.ID_MODELO = TBMO.ID_MARCA
    INNER JOIN TB_MARCA TBMA
    ON TBMO.ID_MARCA = TBMA.ID_MARCA
    INNER JOIN TB_CONDICAO TBC
    ON TBA.ID_CONDICAO = TBC.ID_CONDICAO
    INNER JOIN TB_TIPO_ANUNCIO TBTA
    ON TBA.ID_TIPO_ANUNCIO = TBTA.ID_TIPO_ANUNCIO

    IF UPDATE(TB_ANUNCIO)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TB_HISTORICO(ID_ANUNCIO, ID_EVENTO, DT_HISTORICO, NM_ANUNCIO, DS_ANUNCIO, VL_ANUNCIO, QT_ANUNCIADA, SN_IMG_ALTERADA, NM_CATEGORIA,
    NM_SITUACAO, NM_MODELO, NM_MARCA, NM_CONDICAO, NM_TIPO_ANUNCIO)
    VALUES(@Id_Anuncio, @Id_Evento, GETDATE(), @Nome_anuncio, @Descricao, @Valor, @Qtd, @Sn_Img, @Nm_Categoria, @Nm_Situacao,
    @Nm_Modelo, @Nm_Marca, @Nm_Condicao, @Nm_Tipo_Anuncio)

    END
END;
```

Comment: Neste IF UPDATE() se requer uma coluna ...  https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.